# Hsqldb single quote character

Tags: hsqldb

How can I insert single quote character to Hsqldb table? Escape character doesn't work for the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways.

1. Use two single quotes. For example `INSERT INTO T VALUES 'escap''d'`
2. Use a Unicode string, which can contain a Unicode escape. For example `INSERT INTO T VALUES U&'escap\0027d'`

Both examples insert the string `escap'd` into the table.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but I found the answer by fredt but it led me astray because it doesn't actually do what the original poster requested which is insert a single quote. Instead it inserts escap'd which is not what I wanted to do.

This may have been the only way in the past (Fred would know better than me), but the easiest way in hsqldb to insert a single quote now is to just make a **prepared statement in java** (p_insert) and set the String:

p_insert.setString(1,"'");
p_insert.executeUpdate();

This will actually put a single quote in the database, at least in version 2.3.2. To retrieve it from the database, you will need to use **double single quotes** in your SELECT statement.

Comment: `INSERT INTO T VALUES ''''` (with 4 single quote characters) inserts one single quote character into the table.