# Embedding a newline in a string literal in HSQLDB

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I can hardly believe I need to ask this, but there really doesn't seem to be any documentation on it in the HSQLDB documentation.

What's the way to put a newline into a string literal for HSQLDB (it's part of a test data set I'm using). I have a statement like:

```
INSERT INTO "RANDOM_TABLE" ("TEXT_VALUE") 
VALUES ('BRAF >> V600E (73%)\nPIK3CA >> E545G (31%)');
```

And I'd really like the `\n` or equivalent to be a newline character. Except, of course `\n` just passes through as is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I admit this was surprisingly hard to google, but this worked for me:

```
CREATE TABLE baz (
 col VARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO baz
VALUES (U&'foo\000Abar');
```

Of course depending on your platform you may want to use \000A, \000D or \000D\000A (respectively: LF, CR or LF followed by CR).

By the way, credits to this post: [Hsqldb single quote character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397186/hsqldb-single-quote-character)

Comment: Amazing. Many thanks. And it's interesting that it's this horrible.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server has a [CHAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx) function to let you insert a character by [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) character number.

Character **13** is for **Line Feed** and **10** is **Carriage Return**. Sometimes you need one and sometimes you need both.

```
INSERT INTO "RANDOM_TABLE" ("TEXT_VALUE") 
VALUES ('BRAF >> V600E (73%)' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'PIK3CA >> E545G (31%)');
```

Comment: I'd actually like to accept both answers, as they'll both solve the problem, but I was looking for an escaping solution. Upvote anyways.

Comment: This one worked for me, the accepted answer didn't.